# How do I rename a mounted Truecrypt volume?

Tags: truecrypt

When I mount the Truecrypt file on my USB drive it shows up as truecrypt1.

The volume is FAT, using mtools to rename a volume label involves `e2label /dev/sdbx`, however truecrypt1 does not map to a physical partition. `fdisk -l` does not show the volume partition (only the physical USB device), and `df -h` lists the volume path as `/dev/mapper/truecrypt1`.

Finally, using the Nautilus 'Rename' context action, gives the error: "Sorry, could not rename "truecrypt1" to "towel": Operation not supported by backend".

Apparently this [can be done in Win](http://www.advpc.net/encrypt14.html), but how can I rename this volume in Ubuntu?

---

As Nicolas said, specifying the mount point names the partition the same. The truecrypt GUI does not remember the mount point I set, so I specify the mount points in a script which I placed in my main menu.

```
#!/bin/bash
gksudo truecrypt /media/usbdrive/encryptedfile /media/securedata/
```

Comment: I've been wondering how to do this too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a mount point in order to do what you want. 
If I want my truecrypt1 volume to show up as "Private", I'll create a "Private" mountpoint with `sudo mkdir /media/Private`
Then launch Truecrypt, select my encrypted drive and when I click on "Mount" I'm asked for my password and I can click "Option" to select my custom mount point. 
Voilà, it's done.

Comment: Although this does not set the encrypted volume label, this is a good alternative that achieves the same result. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 4):

The prior solutions did not work if you have ext3/4 volumes.  This is a solution for that case:

1. Find the ID using >> sudo fdisk -l

> Disk **/dev/mapper/truecrypt2**: 128.8 GB, 128000000000 bytes
>   255 heads, 60 sectors/track, 15000 cylinders, total 250000000 sectors
>   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x1234567

Find the ID (bolded above) for the volume of interest.  Your location WILL be different!

1. Use e2label: >> sudo e2label /dev/mapper/truecrypt2 newname

Again, make sure you use YOUR drive information.